# Linux manage permissions of a folder

Tags: debian, permissions, users

I have folder to which multiple users write and edit files, the problem is that the files are used by a app and to start that app it needs permissions (read+write), but the edited files belong to the user which edited it, I was setting it via script before the start of the program, but the files are too large and its very heavy operation for the harddrive to set permissions to 100K files everytime I want to start my app. Any work around ?

Comment: If you set `umask 0002`, then by default all files will be created with user and group write permission. You can either put all users into the same group, or add a specific group to all users who use the app.

Comment: If you follow AFH's advice and create a dedicated group then you may encounter this issue: [*How to maintain the ownership of a file after editing?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368636/108618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches:

- The "classic" one is using the so-called *group sticky bit:*

  On Linux, the "group sticky bit" set on a directory makes all the files created in that directory have their owner group set to that of the containing directory — as opposed to the user's primary group, which is the default.

  There's how to do this:

  1. Add all the users into a dedicated group.
  2. Set owner group on that directory to that new group.
  3. Modify the permissions on that directory to include `g=rwxs` — that is,
     enable the group sticky bit while at the same time granting
     the members of that group "sensible" access.
  4. Make each user have the `umask` value of the process they use for editing these files not mask out the group permission bits — that is, `002` or `007` are okay but `022` is not as it would make the files created in the directory have `g-w` in their permission bits hence preventing the other users from editing the files.

  See the ["Linux filesystem permissions demystified"](https://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/22/linux-permissions-demystified/) for more info.
- Use POSIX ACLs to fine-tune the access rights.

  This is an oft-forgotten venue, but since ages Debian comes with
  this feature enabled by default in the kernel and on the filesystems
  which support it.

  You might start with [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions#Default_.28inherited.29_ACL).